# Create shortcut on desktop that opens url in Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, vbscript

We use a webpage in that only works in IE. I create a shortcut on the desktop that  uses the target of `"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" http:\\sampleurl.com`. This opens the page in IE but what I want to do is create a vbs that my GPO can run and create the icon for all users on my network that need it. Here is what I have so far, but it doesn't open it in IE.

```
' Define variables.

Dim WSHShell 
Dim MyShortcut 
Dim DesktopPath

Set WSHShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
If not WSHShell Is Nothing Then 
DesktopPath = WSHShell.SpecialFolders("Desktop") 
Set MyShortcut = WSHShell.CreateShortCut(DesktopPath & "\Visions" & ".lnk") 
MyShortcut.TargetPath = "https://www.sampleurl.com"
MyShortcut.WorkingDirectory = "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop" 
MyShortcut.WindowStyle = 1 
MyShortcut.Arguments = "" 
MyShortcut.Save 
Set MyShortcut = Nothing 
end if
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok I figured it out. I needed to set the `MyShortcut.armguments` to the URL and the `MyShortcut.TargetPath` to IE.

```
' Define variables.

Dim WSHShell 
Dim MyShortcut 
Dim DesktopPath

Set WSHShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
If not WSHShell Is Nothing Then 
DesktopPath = WSHShell.SpecialFolders("Desktop") 
Set MyShortcut = WSHShell.CreateShortCut(DesktopPath & "\Visions" & ".lnk") 
MyShortcut.TargetPath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"
MyShortcut.WorkingDirectory = "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop" 
MyShortcut.WindowStyle = 1 
MyShortcut.Arguments = "https://visions.apscc.org/Citrix/XenApp/auth/login.aspx?CTX_MessageType=WARNING&CTX_MessageKey=NoUsableClientDetected" 
MyShortcut.Save 
Set MyShortcut = Nothing 
end if
```

Comment: You don't need `VBscript`: you can create a direct link on your desktop (right-click -> New -> Shortcut) and set the target as the full path to IE and the website parameter (with quotes as needed).

Comment: Yes except I don't want to have to drive all over creation and do this for each user. There are other and that go with this so the user never knows it wasn't already setup.

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT I completely agree. This is just a small portion of a GPO that will setup the shortcut, install the software they need, and map their drive they will need.

Comment: You can create it for all users in the Public Desktop.

Comment: Don't want all users to have access to it. This does exactly what I want. I have added this to a GPO and then given the user group access to the GPO. Total package works like a charm.

Comment: Fine. I wasn't aware of these other conditions when I made my comments. I'm glad you've got a solution.